# Finding two constants in regards to R square... time consuming

Tags: octave

I've successfully written a script that loads the value of an XLS file. The rawdata consists of stiffness values, frequencies as well as temperature.

I've created a for loop for finding 2 constants (x1 and x2) I need to be able to make a superposition of the data.

This works but takes quite alot of time.

The code looks roughly like this:

```
oldRsqr = 0;
x1_found = 0;
x2_found = 0;

for i = 0:0.1:10000
 for j = 0:0.1:10000

x1 = i;
x2 = j;

wanted_value = -x1*(T_T-T_ref)./(x2+(T_T-T_ref)

ReqT = exp(wanted_value(:,1));
ReqCalc = ReqT.*Req_tot;
Rsqr = corr(log(ReqCalc),log(ForceIndata))

if Rsqr > oldRsqr
Rsqr = oldRsqr;
x1_found = x1;
x2_found = x2;
elseif Rsqr <= oldRsqr
Rsqr = oldRsqr;
break;
endif

endfor
endfor
```

I've looked at `fminsearch` but haven't really seen how to use it. The same goes for `fsolve` since I want the R square to be as high as possible. Higher R square = higher acuracy = better chosen constants.

I've also made a longer version of this that does the testing in steps.

For instance starting the first for loop at

```
for i = 0:100:10000
for j = 0:100:10000
i_1_min = x1_found-100;
i_1_max = x1_found+100;

j_1_min = x2_found-100;
j_1_max = x2_found+100;
```

....

```
i_2_min =  x1_found-100;
i_2_max =  x1_found+100;
i_2_min =  x2_found-100;
i_2_max =  x2_found+100;
```

then the next for loop would be

```
for i_2 = i_2_min:10:i_2_max
for j_2 = j_2_min:10:j_2_max
```

and so on and so on... you get the drill.

There must be a more time efficient way of finding two constants that would optimize my equation?

If excel can do this in a few seconds with solver this should be an easy task for something as powerful as Octave? Or am I wrong?